# What must be the return type of TokenEndPoint(of a WEBAPI project) if it is being called from an MVC separate project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

This is from WebAPI Project

```
public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> property in context.Properties.Dictionary)
    {
        context.AdditionalResponseParameters.Add(property.Key, property.Value);
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

This is from MVC Controller

```
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:30760/Token", encodedRequest).Result;
```

My question is , the return of `return Task.FromResult<object>(null);`gives a blank page on web browser BUT what i need is a return to the controller , in

```
HttpResponseMessage response= httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:30760/Token", encodedRequest).Result;
```

So what am I missing, given that I have a username and password which Im not going to put here cause its not the issue I think.

Controller

```
    public class SupplierController : Controller
{
    string Baseurl = "http://localhost:30760/TryAPI";
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var tokenRequest =
                new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username","tested@gmail.com"),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "P@ssw0rd")
                    };

            HttpContent encodedRequest = new FormUrlEncodedContent(tokenRequest);

            HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:30760/Token", encodedRequest).Result;
            var responseToken = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var convertedResponseToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseToken);
            // Store token in ASP.NET Session State for later use
           // Session["ApiAccessToken"] = convertedResponseToken["AccessToken"];
        }

        List<string> EmpInfo = new List<string>();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Session["ApiAccessToken"].ToString());


            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/values");

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                EmpInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(EmpResponse);

            }
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return View(EmpInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: could you please elaborate this `the return of return Task.FromResult<object>(null);gives a blank page on web browser BUT what i need is a return to the controller , in`

Comment: I never had any chance on asking a question without being not understood,

Comment: here, in my mvc project controller ,i need to pass a username and password to webapi after INSIDE webapi we have a controller called public override Task TokenEndpoint(OAuthTokenEndpointContext context), ok , so next i need that method or action to return to mvc project but it gives me a no return at all even the web browser doesnt say anything 200, 404, 500 , NOTHING, i have this theory that the main reason why im not returning to mvc project is because of this  return Task.FromResult<object>(null); MVC project is waiting.... this is the code that is waiting HttpResponseMessage response

Comment: did u try it with Postman?

Comment: you want access token in response but it doesn't return anything, right?

Comment: i tried using webapi project alone without postman, its working,

Comment: did u implement those override methods: `ValidateClientAuthentication`, `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` with your `TokenEndpoint`? if not then you can't get token in anyway

Comment: im trying to have mvc project to access the web api using httpclient, i did successfully without [Authorize], but then ofcourse in reality they should have username and password(owned by webapi datatabase), i wish not to create a new token creator in webapi so i want to continue using the integrated webapi tokengenerator of microsoft but then the return is return Task.FromResult<object>(null);, so am i missing anything , i wish to go back to mvc project's HttpResponseMessage response, this is all what i want to happen this upcoming christmas

Comment: Yes ive seen GrantResourceOwnerCredentials  in Providers folder in WebAPI Project, mind you that I have two projects separated with each other WebAPI and the MVC Project

Comment: please add your mvc controllers code in your post that you try to call `PostAsync` method

Comment: i am running in multiple projects, so from mvc project i can go to web api's GrantResourceOwnerCredentials then TokenEndpoint then blank page , so i wish to return the response back to mvc project

Comment: there i added it now

Comment: I'll try your code on my side, if i get success then I'll let you know :)

Comment: thanks, i found something saying its a deadlock and the reason why i cant go back to mvc's httpclient method is because the two parties(mvc and web api) are all async